# Akka stream: using persistence queues or event sourcing

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-persistence

In an Akka stream application, if the application crashes/node goes down, I run the risk of losing the in-flight messages.

What can be done to ensure we don't lose the messages and they are played once the application comes back.

In my application, mapAsyns do IO calls and some minor CPU bound tasks.

In a pure Akka application I will go for either persistent queues or event sourcing. But in case of Akka stream since I don't have access to the underlying queues, how can I ensure that no message inside the stream is lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to checkpoint the stream sink and then resume the source based on the last successful checkpoint if it crashes. You can do the checkpoint and resume using a persistent queue or event sourcing as you mention.

Comment: So effectively, if my source does not support replay, I will need to custom build one where I fetch data from the real source (say Rabbit MQ or Kinesis) and push it to a persistent store! I would also need custom logic while materializing the stream to ensure I reset my source to the checkpoint. How can I make this more generic and say that I make every stage in the stream best effort deliver once (I know best effort does not go with deliver once, but probably you get the idea)?

Comment: Well, if your source isn't transactional you're going to have to build transactions any way you cut it, right? If you can defer either block the read, or somehow otherwise acknowledge it, then you can read it with a stream, write it to a persistent actor, and only unblock the ack once it's all done.